# Using the addition operator on a generic subclass of Number

Tags: java, generics

Can someone tell me why this code gives me a compile-error?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(2, 6.9));
    }

    public static <T extends Number<T>> T sum(T a, T b) {
        T result = a + b;      // compile-error here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Number` is not a generic class, so you can't parameterize it:

```
public abstract class Number implements java.io.Serializable {
...
}
```

Further, the `+` operator only works on primitive types like `int`, `long`, etc., rather than `Number` subtypes like `Integer`, `Long`, etc.  (EDIT: It will operate on these by unboxing, yes, but it cannot automatically box the result in the appropriate wrapper class.)

(You've stumbled upon one of the reasons `Number` is a poor example of polymorphism.  It really only performs object-to-primitive conversions.)

Comment: So i cant use generics to add or subtract?

Comment: Why not just make an `add` method?

Comment: Actually, `+` works perfectly well on `Integer`, `Double`, etc. (any type for which an unboxing conversion is defined). Unfortunately for OP, [the rules for unboxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) do not defined unboxing for the abstract class `Number`, only for its predefined concrete subclasses.

Comment: Just as a note, Groovy adds these kinds of methods and turns operators into calls to those methods.  That allows you to implement, say, `Foo.add` then add `Foo` objects using `+`.

Comment: @AlanKrueger - Apples and oranges. [Groovy isn't a superset of Java](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/groovy-isnt-a-superset-of-java/). It looks enough like Java to confuse people, but, unlike Java, it supports dynamic typing, operator overloading, closures (so sometimes semicolons are required, while most times they are optional), etc. Might as well point out that C++ supports defining `+` for the classes of your choice; it would be just as (ir)relevant.

Comment: Except that Groovy runs on the JVM and can interoperate with Java classes just fine. It's hardly irrelevent, and it was merely an aside.

Answer (score 2):

You can, instead create an interface with

```
public interface ALU  <T extends Number> {

    public  T add(T a, T b);
}
```

And make your main class implementing the interface created.

```
public class Main implements ALU <Integer>.
```

And create the method add inside your main class.

```
public Integer add(Integer a, Integer  b){
        return a + b;
    }
```

And this will work.

Comment: The whole point of question was to parameterize the add method, so..

Answer (score 1):

The error `The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T` is caused because `The type Number is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T>`

The error highlighting in eclipse provides this information, not sure if other IDE's provide the same information.

Comment: but i thought that was the point of generics. let the compiler handle the types

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
a.doubleValue()+b.doubleValue()
```

as Number is a class and does not support the operator +